# Datatable: How to write a headline to place of 'Show x entries'

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using the`datatable` for my project. I want to use the place of `Show x entries` as the headline of my table.

I know how to remove `Show x entries` from the `Datatable`. But I could not find how to write my headline like the below example:

[image]